# Hitting time of the simple processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In Protter's book, they defined a stopping time for the simple process $H_u^k(\omega)$ as $$R_k=\inf\{t:|H_u^k|>\eta\}.$$

Since the simple process is left continuous with right limit and $R_k$ is the hitting time into an open set. I am not really convinced that $R_k$ is indeed a stopping time. How can I see that? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition of the process and the left-continuity of $H$ $$\{R_k > t\} = \bigcup_{s \le t,~ s\in\mathbb Q} \left\{H_s^k \le \eta\right\}$$ Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable and $\left\{H_s^k \le \eta\right\} \in \mathcal {F}_t, \forall s \le t$, we have $\{R_k > t\} \in \mathcal F_t$ which proves that $R_k$ is a stopping time.

Comment: Do you mean $\{R_k<t}\$

Comment: No I meant $\{R_k > t\}$. But since $\{R_k > t\} \in \mathcal F_t$ the complementary set $\{R_k \le t\}$ is also in $\mathcal F_t$

Comment: Sorry, there is one last question remaining. Your proof seems also to work for $\{R_k \geq t\}$. Can I replace your $\{R_k > t\}$ with $\{R_k \geq t\}$?

Comment: I think if $H_s^k$ is continuous $\{R_k \ge t\} = \{R_k > t\}$

Comment: And what if I insist on left-continuity only? And provided I have right-continuous filtration.

Comment: Left-continuous is enough to have $\{R_k \ge t\} = \{R_k > t\}$